# Independencia en el Contexto de una vista usando Partial o RenderPartial asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, vistas, asp.net-mvc-4

Hola gente me podrían ayudar

Aver si me explico:

Tengo una vista Index qe tiene una tabla e incluye varias veces la misma vista parcial(llamada prev) en los espacios de la tabla, cada (prev.cshtml)con diferente tamaño, dentro de la vista parcial (prev) agregue un metodo javascript para detectar en tamaño del 'div' principal de cada (prev) usando el id del div principal de prev.
   El problema es que parece ser que cada vista parcial (prev) no tiene independencia, por qe al ejecutar, la función js me da siempre el tamaño del primer (prev), como si la función se ejecutara una ves con cada (prev) pero en el ámbito de la vista padre, es como que al tener cada div principal del prev el mismo id la función trabaja siempre sobre el primero, lo cual no pasaría si las vistas parciales tuvieran algo así como un contexto independiente.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias!
Pero es una buena practica generar los IDs en tiempo de ejecución con algún parámetro recibido, o conoces alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que las "vistas parciales" es un concepto que únicamente existe en el servidor y que sirve precisamente para encapsular código de las vistas que se repite varias veces en diferentes sitios.

Sin embargo, una vez procesada la vista (con las diferentes vistas parciales incluidas), la salida generada por el motor de vistas de ASP.Net MVC va a ser el código HTML de una única página a mostrar en una ventana de navegador. A partir de ese momento no existe ninguna división entre el código generado por la vista principal, el layout o las vistas parciales.

Por eso, cuando el navegador muestra en la ventana el código HTML recibido, muestra la página generada a partir de este código HTML construyendo con sus elementos un único árbol DOM. Esto es algo que deberías tener en cuenta a la hora de generar los `id`s de los elementos (ya que éstos deberían ser únicos).

También deberías evitar incluir código javascript en las vistas parciales y sacarlo  a archivos externos. De esta forma evitarás que, por ejemplo, se defina la misma función varias veces  cuando incluyas varias veces la misma vista parcial.

El navegador, por tanto, es agnóstico respecto a cómo se ha generado el código HTML recibido ni tiene constancia de la existencia de las vistas parciales.